# PowerShell: Start-Process with wait option taking long time to return

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have the following script:

```
$mArgs = @('myProj.vcxproj', '/t:Clean,Build' ,('/p:configuration=DEBUG'+';platform=win32;OutDir=./'))
Start-Process msbuild.exe -ArgumentList $mArgs -RedirectStandardOutput $tempFile -wait
```

The above successfully builds myProj. However, it takes a really long time to return. When the above line is reached, I see the msbuild windows for about 2 minutes. Then, it closes. After that, it takes another 8 minutes for the process to complete. If I just run the above in a cmd window, it takes about 2 minutes for it to complete. 
I tried starting the process cmd.exe and passing msbuild as a parameter, but got the same result. 
I also tried Invoke-Expression and also got the same results.

Does anyone have a clue what can be causing this delay ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this `--ArgumentList ` a typo in the question?  It should be just `-ArgumentList`.  BTw after the MSBUILD window goes away do you still see the process running in task manager?

Comment: It's a typo; I just fixed it.
After the msbuild window goes away, it also disappears from the task manager.

Answer (score 5):

I am using PowerShell v4.0 Start-Process for running MSBuild on Win2012R2. Usually build time of my solution is 1 min, but on build server it is 16 min. **It takes MSBuild 15 min to close all nodes** and finally exit (16 min to print "Finished!!!").

PowerShell code:

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $fileName -ArgumentList $arguments
 -WorkingDirectory $workingDir -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait
Write-Host "Finished!!!"
$exitCode = $process.ExitCode
```

MSBuild args:

```
$commandLine = "/nologo /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 /maxcpucount:2"
 + " "+ $dir + "MySolution.sln"
```

After adding **/nodeReuse:false** to MSBuild command line the build time is back to normal (1min).

Here is the working code:

```
function PsStartProcess([string]$fileName, [array]$arguments, [string]$workingDir)
{
    if (!$workingDir)
    {
        $workingDir = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
    }

    $process = Start-Process -FilePath $fileName -ArgumentList $arguments -WorkingDirectory $workingDir -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait
    Write-Host "Finished!!!"
    $exitCode = $process.ExitCode
    $process.Close()

    return $exitCode
}

$exeFileName = "c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
$commandLine = "/nologo /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 /maxcpucount:2 /nodeReuse:false" + " "+ $dir + "MySolution.sln"
PsStartProcess $exeFileName $commandLine $binDir
```

Comment: I have similar issue with `devenv` in powershell. Script is stuck for some time on the line but log says it finished compiling. With cmd, this was not the case

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue using `devenv.exe` to compile like this

```
Start-Process $devenv $args -Wait
```

That would take forever. I reformatted the code to this

```
$proc = Start-Process $devenv $args -PassThru 
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

And it is flying. In my case it is compilation of multiple solutions (40+) in the loop, and in perf-mon I don't see many active MSBuild/Devenv processes. There are few of each but all "terminated". And memory is OK. So, good option.

Comment: Bizarrely, this switch from -Wait to .WaitForExit() also solves the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Start-Process to run MSBUILD?  I run it directly within PowerShell e.g.:

```
C:\PS> msbuild myproj.vcxproj /t:clean`,build /p:configuration=DEBUG`;platform=win32`;OutDir=. > $tempfile
```

Just be sure to escape the characters that PowerShell would normally interpret like `,` and `;`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today. What I found is that msbuild waits for VBCSCompiler.exe (located in the visual studio installation folder) to close. There is a config to this exe with a keepalive setting which defaults to 600 seconds. Setting this to 1 second will bypass this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just observed the script and found that the first Line of the script seems to have a missing Single Quote. Please try again with the missing quote and report if that helps?

Comment: I skipped the quote when typing the question. I've added it now. Result is still the same.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 7 the process returns immediately after completion of the build, but on Windows 8 I have the same problem. If possible, I'll try to test with some other environments as well.